# How to share a single instance of an object among multiple actions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux, react-redux

I have a React/Redux application that talks alot to an API and deals with a lot of rarely changing data from a DB. In order to reduce traffic and improve UE, I now want to create a caching mechanism that stores data on the client by automatically using the best technology that is available (descending from IndexedDB to LocalStorage etc.).

I created a `cache` object that does an initial check which determines the storage mechanism (which gets saved to an *engine* property, so the check just needs to run once). It also has some basic methods `save(key, value)` and `load(key)`, which then call the appropriate functions for the initially determined mechanism.

The cache object and its methods do work, but I wonder how to create the cache in my main `index.js` only once when the application loads, and then use this very object in my actions without recreating another cache object every time?

BTW: It feels wrong to make the cache part of my application state as it does not really contain substantial data to run the application (if there is no caching available, it falls back to just calling the API).

Do I need to *inject* the cache into my actions somehow? Or do I need to create a global/static cache object in the main `window` object?

Thanks for clarification and thoughts on this issue.

Answer (score 3):

redux-thunk middleware offers a [custom argument injection](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#injecting-a-custom-argument) feature you could use.

When creating the store

```
const cache = createCache()

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(cache))
)
```

Then in your action creator

```
function getValue(id) {
  return (dispatch, getState, cache) => {
    // use cache
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising - no pun intended ;) I will have a look.